# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

Output PHP with json_encode below :

```
{"data_1":"Data 1","data_2":"Data 2"}
```

In jQuery I have code :

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'process.php',
    dateType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data : {val : data_val},
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            alert(key+ " " + value);
        });
    }
});
```

But when run it show error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '36' in....

Why? And How to fix it?

Comment: this code seems fine, there may be another issue

Comment: Process.php is very simple code like this : '<?php
$data = array(
"data_1" => "Data 1",
"data_2" => "Data 2");
echo json_encode($data);'

Comment: terminate code after `echo json_code($data); die;` section, and remove white spaces outsides from `<?php ?>` code.

Comment: @Girish Actually, the best way is to do not close the `<?php` tag at the end. And **PLEASE**, never use a stray `die()`. Those are a terrible idea and cause non-clean exits.

Comment: Nothing outsite <?php /* CODE */?> and I was add die(); after echo but still error.

Comment: Error still here. Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think the json data which you have is not converted to json `object`

to do that use `data = JSON.parse(data);` then try the `each` loop

or

send application/json header from php , like `header("Content-Type:application/json");`. If proper json header is sent then the browser will do the parsing for you.

so your final code will look something like

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'process.php',
    dateType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data : {val : data_val},
    success: function(data){
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            alert(key+ " " + value);
        });
    }
});
```

OR (in php)

```
header("Content-Type:application/json");
$data = array( "data_1" => "Data 1", "data_2" => "Data 2"); 
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Why I was use json_encode but my code is not converted to json ?

Comment: it IS converting to json and echoing.. but when the browser receives it i thinks that it is a html response since the proper header was not sent. so it doesnt parses it.